# git push to bitbucket fails immediately

Tags: git, bitbucket, bitbucket-server

With error *Unable to lookup 'my bitbucket account' (port 9418) (A non-recoverable error occurred during a database lookup.)* on a corporate bitbucket repository. It fails so quickly, it doesn't seem to be looking up anything. It almost feels like I need to clear out cache, but don't know if that's even possible.

It has worked in the past with no issues and seems to be all of a sudden. I can log into the repository with no problem. Error only happens on push, clone, or pull.

Comment: If this is a corporate bitbucket server instance you should likely engage your internal support team for bitbucket. As an end user you're unlikely to be able to provide any info that SO/Atlassian Community can resolve.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to assume, based on that port, that you're using the native git protocol on port 9418 instead of HTTPS or SSH - and that, therefore, you're using Bitbucket Server instead of Bitbucket Cloud. Either way, the git protocol is not supported (https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BSERV-2508 for Server, https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issues/11899/not-able-to-use-git-protocol-url for Cloud).

Are you able to push/pull/clone/etc using HTTPS or SSH instead?

Comment: So, it seems the configuration is fine. I re-booted my machine and it worked as normal. So I think there is something that's cached and not allowing it to do its thing. Shouldn't have to reboot every time I want to push though.